# nsurlconnection in picker view in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

i am new to iOS i am struggling lot to showing  particular object for value(id) in picker view using nsurlconnection POST method.when i click button it show all value of "id" using nslog but not in picker view.

coding

Button action:

```
-(IBAction)sendDataUsingGet:(id)sender{

    [self sendDataToServer : @"GET"];
    [self.pickerdata reloadAllComponents];
    [self.view addSubview:pickerdata];

}
```

Delegate method:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSMutableString *responseStringWithEncoded = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData: mutableData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //NSLog(@"%@",responseStringWithEncoded  );// this nslog will display all d response....
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: mutableData
                                                         options:kNilOptions
                                                           error:&error]; //Now we got top level dictionary


    arry = [json valueForKeyPath:@"BranchByList.id"];
    NSLog(@"%@",arry);   

    NSAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[responseStringWithEncoded dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
    serverResponse.attributedText = attrStr;

}
```

Picker view:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView;{
    return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component;{
    return [arry count];
    //[self.pickerdata reloadAllComponents];
}

-(NSString*) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component;{

    return [[arry objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:@"currency"];
    //[self.pickerdata reloadAllComponents];
}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{
    NSLog([arry objectAtIndex:row]);

}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use NSURLConnection in new projects, it's deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are reloading picker components before data arrived from server.

You should call `[self sendDataToServer : @"GET"];` this from viewdidload instead of button click so when user press button then data already arrived. i think in your case picker view reloaded before data is come from server.

or you can put `[self.pickerdata reloadAllComponents];` this statement in `connectionDidFinishLoading` method as last statement. so whenever response is come then it reload pickerview. and you can put this both lines

```
  [self.pickerdata reloadAllComponents];
  [self.view addSubview:pickerdata];
```

to `connectionDidFinishLoading` method instead of buttonclick method. so when you click button just your `get` method get called and when response comes then it reload picker and show to view but it takes some time to show picker. so better way is call webservice in viewdidload when viewcontroller is load and make your `array` ready before user click button and when user click reload data and show picker.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: what's problem you are getting exactly ? are you able to display picker view (empty) ? or your picker view is not displayed?

Comment: picker view empty with single line @Lion

Comment: Do you have set `yourPickerView.delegate = self` and `yourPickerView.datasource = self` ?  and in your .h file have you conform protocol to UIPickerViewDelegate and UIPickerViewDatasource ?

Comment: can you post your array which you get from server ?

Comment: and put braek point in `numberOfRowsInComponent` and `titleForRow` method and check what array count is and what is string every time return by  `titleForRow`

Answer (score 0):

[image: screenshot for "id"]You should call reload data, after assign new data for arry Array

```
-(IBAction)sendDataUsingGet:(id)sender{    
                [self sendDataToServer : @"GET"];
                //Show some loading views here 

         }


        -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
        {
            NSMutableString *responseStringWithEncoded = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData: mutableData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            //NSLog(@"%@",responseStringWithEncoded  );// this nslog will display all d response....
            NSError* error;
            NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: mutableData
                                                                 options:kNilOptions
                                                                   error:&error]; //Now we got top level dictionary


            arry = [json valueForKeyPath:@"BranchByList.id"];
            NSLog(@"%@",arry);   

            NSAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[responseStringWithEncoded dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
            serverResponse.attributedText = attrStr;

        //Hidden loading views
        ...
        // Reloading data

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.view addSubview:pickerdata];
            [self.pickerdata reloadAllComponents];

        });

    }
```